# Using 2dc_jqgrid, how do I display customized data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid with Ruby on Rails using the 2dc_jqgrid plugin -- [2dc_jqgrid details](http://www.2dconcept.com/jquery-grid-rails-plugin)).

By default, the plugin seems to take information directly from the fields in your model and display them in the resulting table. For instance:

```
books = Book.find(:all) do
  if params[:_search] == "true"

    id =~ "%#{params[:id]}%" if params[:id].present?

    model =~ "%#{params[:name]}%" if params[:model].present?

    manufacturer =~ "%#{params[:publisher]}%" if params[:publisher].present?

  end
  paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => params[:rows]      
  order_by "#{params[:sidx]} #{params[:sord]}"
end
if request.xhr?
  render :json => books.to_jqgrid_json([:id,:name,:publisher], params[:page], params[:rows], camera_grids.total_entries) and return
end
```

With this default setup, the manufacturer's ID will be displayed in the resulting table (e.g., 12). I want to display the publisher's name. A book belongs to a publisher so I'd like to specify book.publisher.name. I am not sure how or where I can do this with 2dc_jqgrid.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This works with rails 3. Here an example:

```
  def index

    index_columns ||= [:act, :id, :username, :firstname, :lastname, 'language.name', :disable]
    current_page = params[:page] ? params[:page].to_i : 1
    rows_per_page = params[:rows] ? params[:rows].to_i : 10

    conditions={:page => current_page, :per_page => rows_per_page}
    conditions[:order] = params["sidx"] + " " + params["sord"] unless (params[:sidx].blank? || params[:sord].blank?)

    if params[:_search] == "true"
      conditions[:conditions] = filter_by_conditions(index_columns)
    end

    @accounts = Account.paginate(conditions)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @accounts.to_jqgrid_json(index_columns, current_page, rows_per_page, @accounts.count) }
    end
  end
```